# Access current `$route.path` inside of nuxt.config.js

Tags: nuxt.js

I want to set `og:url` in my Nuxt SSR project. I am attempting to do this in the `nuxt.config.js` file however I can not seem to get access to `this.$route.path`. This is my current code below.

**nuxt.config.js**

```
require('dotenv').config()

export default {
  mode: 'universal',
  target: 'static',

  generate: {
    fallback: true
  },

  env: {
    baseUrl: process.env.BASE_URL || 'http://localhost:3000'
  },

  head: () => ({
    meta: [
      {
        hid: 'og:url',
        name: 'og:url',
        content: process.env.baseUrl + this.$route.path
      },
    ],
  }),
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost had it, the issue is that you're giving an arrow function to `head`, and so `this` does not refer to the Nuxt instance, but rather the Javascript object you're exporting in `nuxt.config.js`.

You can even see this in action by replacing your `this.$route.path` call with `this.mode`.  You'll see that `universal` is appended to your content.

Anyways, to fix it, just replace the arrow function with a normal function, which will then give you access to the Nuxt context with `this`:

```
require('dotenv').config()

export default {
    mode: 'universal',
    target: 'static',

    generate: {
        fallback: true
    },

    env: {
        baseUrl: process.env.BASE_URL || 'http://localhost:3000'
    },

    head() {
        // this.$route is undefined when generating the fallback page
        const path = this.$route ? process.env.baseUrl + this.$route.path : process.env.baseUrl
        return {
            meta: [
                {
                    hid: 'og:url',
                    name: 'og:url',
                    content: path
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you run, `npx nuxt build && npx nuxt export` -  TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined

Comment: In that case, you may need to link to a repo reproducing this issue, as I'm able to use that on a fresh Nuxt project without issue

Comment: Try exporting the project with `npx nuxt build && npx nuxt export`

Comment: My apologies, it turns out `this.$route` is undefined in the `head` when Nuxt is generating the fallback page.  I've updated the answer with 1 potential workaround for this.